# jar file under res/raw folder

Tags: android, jar

I need to place a 3rd party jar file as a raw resource under res/raw in my apk. But with Android Studio (Im using 1.3.1), it seems the file disappears from the final apk. Presumably because of the extension of 'jar'.

I cannot rename it and do not want it to be included into dex classes. My app needs to access to the jar runtime as a raw resource.

Any advice (maybe modification to gradle tasks can do) of how this is achieved?

Comment: Why don't you put the file in Asset folder?

Comment: lib folder is there for putting 3rd party jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to official Android documentation you should always put your `.jar` files under the `/libs` folder only.

See the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html),

> raw/
>
> For arbitrary raw asset files. Saving asset files here is essentially
>   the same as saving them in the assets/ directory. The only difference
>   is how you access them. These files are processed by aapt and must be
>   referenced from the application using a resource identifier in the R
>   class. For example, this is a good place for media, such as MP3 or Ogg
>   files.
>
> libs/
>
> Contains private libraries. Stored in the main application
>   module.

Once you have placed a `.jar` file inside the `/libs` folder, you can easily reference it via `gradle.build` file,

For example I've places this **acra-4.6.2.jar** file inside the `/libs` folder

[image]

and made a reference in `gradle.build` file like this,

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/acra-4.6.2.jar')
}
```